# iOS: Blank titles of buttons, labels

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am using the latest software. Xcode 12 and iOS 14

After installing the app from Xcode whether it was a simulator or a real device everything just fine. But, when re-launching the app after stopping the application from running through Xcode everything just blank.
I believe the problem is not related to the appearance mode because I already tried that.

The first image shows the notification page when I run the app through Xcode.
[image]

The second image shows the notification page when I run the app normally (Pressing the app without Xcode). It's not only the notification controller, all the app is facing the issue.

[image]

Comment: Can you post a minimal project that demonstrates this issue?

Comment: unfortunately I can't :)

Comment: Well no one else sees this issue so it’s impossible to help without an actual project.

Comment: if you can give more info about your code, it is hard to find out what is your problem, but if your screen only show icon, all text is visible maybe one of there case: 1. the text color is same as the background color so you can see it, 2. The alpha = 0 or isHidden = true, 3. The label is set with empty string "". Hope this can help you

Comment: Yes, I already tried to check that but it is not related to it. Anyways, Thank you all, I will try to create a new project and copy my code to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just created a new project and copied my code into it. The project worked as expected

Comment: I faced the same issue. Did you solve by creating new project and copying the code? Or did you find what is the problem?

Comment: Yes, I created a new project and copied my code into it and it worked.

Comment: I created new project too. But it didn't work. I solved it in different way. I create an extension that use edgeInset. This extensions breaks my codes. When I delete it everything turn to normal. 
Anyway thanks for your answer.